# Creating a clustered-index in Oracle using an IOT? Confusion

Tags: oracle, indexing

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to use an IOT as a clustered index in oracle. Say I have a table order(order_id,part_id,customer_id,order_date), and I want to create an clustered index using an IOT I would do.

```
CREATE TABLE clust_order(
    order_id number,
    part_id number,
    CONSTRAINT part_pk PRIMARY KEY (part_id)
)ORGANIZATION INDEx;
```

I get that is the equivalent of a clustered index, but I don't get how that relates to the original table. Do I have to insert from the original table into the IOT and then use it in place of the original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from Oracle's [Concepts Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT911)

> "... In an index-organized table, rows are stored in an index defined
>   on the primary key for the table. Each index entry in the B-tree also
>   stores the non-key column values. Thus, the index is the data, and the
>   data is the index."

Suppose we have an ORDER table as described in your question.

```
-- create table ORDER_, with test data
-- table name with trailing underscore avoids ORA-00903: invalid table name
create table order_
as
select 
  level * 10000 + trunc( dbms_random.value * 100 ) order_id
, trunc( dbms_random.value * 100000 )              part_id
, dbms_random.string( 'x', 10 )                    customer_id
, trunc( sysdate + level * 10 )                    order_date
from dual connect by level <= 10 ;
```

**Test data**

```
SQL> select * from order_ ;
ORDER_ID  PART_ID  CUSTOMER_ID  ORDER_DATE  
10069     74711    KBGHAHWTL8   27-MAR-18   
20034     99571    7VUNFJER44   06-APR-18   
30038     64160    ORXP2RRA3K   16-APR-18   
40005     81247    B9N43NSVQ7   26-APR-18   
50019     90889    8H5G12D82E   06-MAY-18   
60017     34107    9O4OSETJ4H   16-MAY-18   
70078     53959    77MUCKJW82   26-MAY-18   
80015     9496     U5J6Z85KXR   05-JUN-18   
90081     88450    2LEUPZGFOS   15-JUN-18   
100031    38487    NX4BHBF3TN   25-JUN-18
```

If you now just create an IOT (index organized table), it will be empty.

```
-- your original code
CREATE TABLE clust_order(
    order_id number,
    part_id number,
    CONSTRAINT part_pk PRIMARY KEY (part_id)
)ORGANIZATION INDEX;

Table CLUST_ORDER created.

SQL> select * from clust_order ;

no rows selected
```

What you could do instead, is: create the IOT by SELECTing from the original table (see also: Parallelizing Index-Organized Table Creation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#ADMIN11685)).

```
create table clust_order 
( 
  part_id constraint part_pk primary key
, order_id 
) 
organization index
parallel
as
select 
  part_id
, order_id 
from order_;
```

The resulting IOT contains ...

```
SQL> select * from clust_order;
PART_ID  ORDER_ID  
9496     80015     
34107    60017     
38487    100031    
53959    70078     
64160    30038     
74711    10069     
81247    40005     
88450    90081     
90889    50019     
99571    20034
```

You may find this [discussion](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:586423377841) useful.

Comment: Awesome. This makes perfect sense, I think I was just having trouble looking at it as a table, even though it is. I think I was just too focused on the clustered index part of it, rather than the TABLE part.

Comment: Cheers!  Best of luck.